# Manipular dois valores diferente no mesmo input text react native expo

Tags: react-native, mobile

Boa noite, estou desenvolvendo uma calculadora para estudar a manipulação de componentes no react native, utilizando o expo, porem estou com um problema de lógica, quando eu digito o primeiro valor1, e depois seleciono um dos tipos de operação (somar, subtrair, dividir etc..) eu queria deixar o  valor1, aparecendo no input text para o usuario, porem se eu manter ele no input text, quando eu for manipular os dados do input text, eu vou acabar somando ele novamente, pois quando eu for obter o valor2 que foi digitado então no input text eu terei o valor1 + valor2 tudo na mesma string, segue meu código

```html
    ChangeText = (i)=>{

        console.log(i);
        if(i >= 0 && i <= 9 && this.state.text_result != null){
            var a = this.state.text_result
            return this.setState({text_result: a + i})
        }else if ( this.state.text_result == null){return this.setState({text_result:i, previw:i})}

        switch(i){
    
            case '=':
                valor2 = this.state.text_result
                
                console.log('Valor2: ',valor2, 'Valor1: ' + valor1 );
                if(tipo == 'soma'){soma = (parseInt(valor1,10) + parseInt(valor2,10))}
                else if (tipo == 'subtracao'){soma = (parseInt(valor1,10) - parseInt(valor2,10))}
                else if (tipo == 'multiplicacao'){soma = (parseInt(valor1,10) * parseInt(valor2,10))}
                console.log(soma);
                this.setState({text_result:soma})
                break;

            case '+':
                valor1 =  this.state.text_result
                tipo = 'soma';
                this.setState({text_result: null})
                break;

            case '-':
                valor1 =  this.state.text_result
                tipo = 'subtracao';
                this.setState({text_result: null})
                break;

            case '*':
                valor1 =  this.state.text_result
                tipo = 'multiplicacao';
                this.setState({text_result: null})
                break;  

            case 'Limpa':
                var a = this.state.text_result;
                this.setState({text_result:null})    
                valor1 = null;
                valor2 = null;
                tipo = null;
                break;
        }
         
    }
```

Eu pensei em manipular a string toda, ou seja deixar o usuario digitar tudo primeiro, exemplo
"100+100" ai através de uma substring pegaria o valor digitado antes do + e depois, porem tambem não consegui fazer a manipulação da substring no react

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Levando em conta que você tem uma string no formato número+símbolo+número, você poderia dar um split no símbolo logo na primeira linha do seu ChangeText.

```js
const [valor1, valor2] = i.split('simbolo'); 
//split retorna um array [a,b]
//A sintaxe de *destrutor* 'destroi o array', obtendo os elementos de acordo com o índice
//Ex. '1000'.split('+')    //Resulta em [1000]
//Ex. '1000+50'.split('+') //Resulta em [1000,   50]
//                                         v      v
//                                const [valor1, valor2] = '1000+50'.split('+')
```

Dessa forma você sempre terá o valor 1 e valor 2 separados.

*Lembrando que essa regra não valeria para mais de um símbolo.*

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, me ajudou muito, eu nunca tinha utilizado a função split.